# Click on Some Area in <a> tag does not work

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

i have a menu that consist of a list of `<li>` .
each `<li>` has a `<a>` in it . and each `<a>` has a `<img>` in it.

My problem is that in some area (close right of `<img>`) of click on `a` does not work, also when i move mouse when clicking

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="user_mg_menu"><a href="#/someurl">TEST<img src="//placehold.it/40/0000ff" /></a></li>
  <li class="group_mg_menu"><a href="#/someurl">TEST1<img src="//placehold.it/40/ff0000" /></a></li>
  <li class="sms_menu"><a href="#/someurl">TEST2<img src="//placehold.it/40/00ff00" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

and this is my css

```
.menu_container {
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.menu  a:active , .menu a:visited , .menu  a {
  color:#336699;
}
.menu li:active {
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-top:4px;
}

.menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin:0 51px 6px 0;
  height: 50px;
}

.menu li {
  width: 185px;  
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
  margin-right:10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #888886;
}

.menu li a {
  line-height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
}

.user_mg_menu {  
  background: /*url('../img/userManagement.png') no-repeat 10px 0,*/ -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f5f7f8, #dcdddf 50% , #f5f7f8 ) ;

  background: /*url('../img/userManagement.png') no-repeat 10px 0,*/ -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5f7f8, #dcdddf 50% , #f5f7f8 ) ; 
}

.group_mg_menu {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f5f7f8, #dcdddf 50% , #f5f7f8 ) ;

  background:  -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5f7f8, #dcdddf 50% , #f5f7f8 ) ;
}
.report_menu
{
  background: /*url('../img/reportMain.png') no-repeat 10px 5px ,*/ -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f5f7f8, #dcdddf 50% , #f5f7f8 ) ;


  background: /*url('../img/userManagement.png') no-repeat 10px 0,*/ -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5f7f8, #dcdddf 50% , #f5f7f8 ) ;
}

.menu  li img {
  float: left;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-top:-5px;
}
```

Here is a Js [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dpNp/) . links set to http://google.com
Click on close right of image does not works .

### [CodePen](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/tyAkn) demo

Comment: @koala_dev, I added a demo.  Soheil, please try to tidy your code up before posting it.  There were a ton of selectors with no bodies, commented out code, and random collections of blank lines.  It makes it hard to work with.  Thanks.

Comment: Demo works fine for me

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when trimming the code and killed the gradient on `.sms_menu`.  It's fixed now in the pen and question.

Comment: TNX @FakeRainBrigand i have add a fiddle . try it .

Comment: @koala_dev try my fiddle . problem exists

Comment: fiddle works fine too

Comment: @koala_dev please go you cursor to the close right side of image and click on it . the page does not go to google.com but click on every area of <a> cause page to reload .

Comment: i think this problem occured because of existence of <img> inside <a> tag

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `padding` from your `a` tag:

```
.menu li a {
    line-height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: i remove padding but problem exists

Comment: a:active work but linking to url not works in close right of image. i think a rendering problem

Comment: Are you talking about the white space between the two images or are you really on the image itself and not possible to click? Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: see this [image](http://i.cubeupload.com/qaxsRS.png) . click on every point of black line does not change the url.

Try it on Latest Version of chrome and Firefox in windows 8

Comment: Could be a problem in Windows 8.

Comment: i dont think . some of my friends check this on other windows version and they have problem too . if you move 2-3 px to right from image and click on it nothing happens

Comment: I believe you, only I can't reproduce it. And nothing in your code suggest that there could be anything.

Comment: i think  a region with 2-3 px from left-right-bottom-top of <img> inside <a> does not work for hyperlinking

Comment: tnx @putvande . try this [link](http://maaha.ir/Menu/)
in some region page doen not direct to google.com